# start PIA VPN at boot not login

Tags: boot, vpn

I'm trying to sort out my downloading box with a vpn, but PIA doesn't seem to run until you login. I need it to start at / soon after boot without any login.

I have tried the PIA beta app, it just starts at login.

I have tried to insert following into rc.local

```
sleep 10
nohup home/user/.piamanger/pia_manager/run.sh
```

doesn't work :(

Any other ideas? I could try a cron job or upstart?

Thanks

Setup:
HP N54L
Ubuntu 14
wake on lan for scheduled downloading via sabnzb

edit
 so now i have tried a cron job with

```
   10  07   *    *    *   /sbin/shutdown -P +2
   11  07   *    *    *   /usr/bin/espeak 'Shutting down in one minute.'
 @reboot n54 /home/n54/.pia_manager/pia_manager/run.sh
```

Which still does not seem to work.

Comment: do cronjob its better.

Answer (score 1):

```
nohup home/user/.piamanger/pia_manager/run.sh
```

is missing a / in front of the script. And "user" needs to be your actual username.

Does `/home/user/.piamanger/pia_manager/run.sh` run without any output?

You can try `/etc/crontab` (that would be my choice).

```
vi /etc/crontab
```

and add

```
@reboot user /home/user/.piamanger/pia_manager/run.sh
```

(again: "user" needs to be your actual username). It might be prudent to catch output into a "log" file (`> /home/user/.piamanger/pia_manager/piamanager.log`) or redirect it (`2>&1`).

Comment: Thanks mate, but still having trouble
 @reboot n54 /home/n54/.pia_manager/pia_manager/run.sh
is in the sudo crontab -e   because thatś where i have some schedule shutdown jobs (this could be a mistake?)

Comment: n54@n54:~$ ./home/n54/.pia_manager/pia_manager/run.sh
bash: ./home/n54/.pia_manager/pia_manager/run.sh: No such file or directory
Thatś odd.  it works without the . at the start ????

Comment: Make the file executable, That might be your original problem even.

Comment: just checked still allow file executing as program¨ is still ticked. Iḿ sure i did chmod u+x it.